# Amazon RDS change collate for mysql database in production without downtime

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I saw a solution like this below:

1. create a new table like your source table.
2. alter that new table the way you want.
3. insert your data into the new table.
4. create indexes etc. as needed on the new table.
5. rename your old table to something like ..._old or whatever.
6. rename your new table to the former name of the old one.
7. copy any missing rows from the _old table to the new one.

[Reference for an above solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6131/mysql-speed-up-execution-of-alter-table)

But the above solution might cause data unavailability if there is a huge amount of data added before copying any missing rows from the _old table to the new one.

Is there any better solution than this, using AWS DMS, etc?

I also want to change the collate of all tables present in the database. Is it possible to get all the data replicated between two RDS DBs continuously, like new data entered in database A gets into Database B and viceversa?

Since I have around 50-60GB data any best way to solve this is appreciated.

**Update:**

- I have around **50-60GB** of data.
- Mysql version: **5.7**
- I need to change collation on all my tables

Comment: If you wrap the entire batch of queries in a single explicit transaction and use proper locking then the table won't be able to be written to until your batch is complete.

Comment: @J.D. it will result in downtime for users who are trying to do write operations right?

Comment: Depends on what you consider downtime. It will cause other write operations on the table to wait. Depending on how long your batch of queries take to run vs how long your application allows waiting before issuing a timeout could result in other write queries to fail. If your batch of queries are quick, then it's unlikely other write queries will timeout.

Comment: @J.D. suppose I have a huge number of users, I can't make them wait by keeping the site in maintenance, etc. Any alternative way?

Comment: Again depends on what you consider downtime. If your batch of queries takes 1 second to run, is that still unacceptable to make the users wait for 1 second?...what about 5 seconds?...10 seconds? To ensure transactional consistency such that you don't lose new data between queries running, the only way to do that is by exclusively locking the table during your changes. Otherwise a non-transactional solution would involve you having to implement a way to synchronize new data from the old table to the new one as it came in, which is more difficult to do, especially in a guaranteed manner.

Comment: As I said, I have around 50-60GB of data and it takes a lot of time. So I need a better solution. I also want to know whether this is possible with AWS DMS or not?

Comment: I don't believe you mentioned your data size anywhere. But I recommend you adding that to your post so others who may be able to help you see that as well. You shoulda also add your table / index definitions and the batch of queries you're currently using.

Comment: Also please note my comments are only in regards to the solution / steps you mentioned in your post. If your goal is to just change the collation of the database or a particular table, there might be a simpler process then the one you proposed that is a non-locking solution, as that may be considered a meta-data type of change. I don't know enough about MySQL in particular to speak to that though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137821/discussion-between-sridhar-raju-and-j-d).

Comment: @J.D. - Only MySQL 8.0 allows DDL statements to be in an explicit transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do most ALTERs with virtually no downtime:  `pt-online-schema-change` (also `gh-ost`).  But they handle one table at a time.

It sounds like you need to change the collation on all the tables.  Or is it really the `CHARACTER SET` you are changing?  (Many people confuse the two.)  Please specify the exact change(s) you want.  And the version of AWS MySQL.

If you change one table at a time, and there is a `JOIN` depending on comparing strings between the tables, then between one table changed and the other being changed, any `JOINs` will not be able to use the index.  This will lead to slowdowns that may be as bad as the Alters, themselves.

Comment: I need to change the collation on all the tables, MySql version is 5.7. Updated the same in the question.